# How to open Javascript popup from iframe window to parent window

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am working in **jsp with javascript** . Here i have use the **iframe** inside parent window. When i cliclk the button in iframe page the popup window will be opened inside iframe page. But i want to show the popup in parent window ? anybody help me.

Iframe look like in parent window:

Comment: Perhaps `parent.open( ... )`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Show the Pop up in iframe outside?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854832/how-to-show-the-pop-up-in-iframe-outside)

Answer (score 0):

**USE:**

```
myFrame.contentWindow.open()
```